# can I open connection between Mysql database and oracle database?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have two databases first one is `Mysql database` and second one is `Oracle database`

what I want to do is update or insert record in oracle database based on 
query result from `Mysql database`

is that possiable in somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but it requires some work, for example with Oracle Database Gateway.

Main steps could be:

- install Oracle Database Gateway
- configure Oracle Database Gateway for MySQL using ODBC
- create a database link in Oracle that refers to MySQL:

  `create database link mylink   connect to "demo"   identified by "demo"   using 'mysql';`
- use the database link in Oracle to access MySQL table `mytable`:

`select ... from mytable@mylink ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem via an ODBC- and/or JDBC-compliant Data Virtualization Platform.
Here's how it works, bearing in mind that you have ODBC-access available to both Oracle and MySQL Database Management Systems (DBMS):

1. You attach MySQL instance to the Data Virtualization Platform
2. You attach Oracle instance to the Data Virtualization Platform
3. You can then perform your Data Manipulation (DML) operations on Data managed by either DBMS as though they are local tables in the Data Virtualization Layer.

Our Virtuoso Multi-Model Database Management and Virtualization Platform is an example of a Data Virtualization solution that operates in the manner described above.

### Related

- [Data Virtualization for Beginners](https://community.openlinksw.com/t/virtuoso-data-virtualization-for-beginners-sql-data-sources/1573)
- [Virtuoso Data Virtualization Platform](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com)